# Changing the color of Gtk.Entry text

Tags: python, css, python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

I want to change the color of text in a `Gtk.Entry`. With `override_color` deprecated, this should be done using CSS, however I do not know how to apply it properly. Could someone help adapt the code below, such that the `change_color` function changes the color of text inside `self.entry`?

```
class Entry(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

        self.entry = Gtk.Entry()

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label='button')
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.change_color)

        box = Gtk.Box()
        box.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
        box.add(self.entry)
        box.add(self.button)

        self.add(box)

    def change_color(self, widget):
        pass

window = Entry()
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long time ago I also had the problem to understand CSS.

It is little complicated to define CSS styles.

```
screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
provider = Gtk.CssProvider()

style_context = Gtk.StyleContext()
style_context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

css = b"""
#green-entry {color: red; background: #dfd} 
#red-button {background: #fdd}
"""   # use prefix `b` or `.encode()` to create `bytes`

provider.load_from_data(css)
#provider.load_from_data("#green-entry {color: red; background: #dfd} #red-button {background: #fdd}".encode())
#provider.load_from_path('app.css')
```

But later you can assing style using CSS name

```
self.entry.set_name('green-entry')

self.button.set_name('red-button')
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

---

You can also assign colors to all widgets usings names like `button`, `entry` (without `#`)

```
css = b"""
entry {color: red; background: #dfd} 
button {background: #fdd}
"""
```

and they will be assigned at start and forever.

But you can still use `set_name()` to assign some modifications.

You can also use `:hover` to change color when mouse hover widget.

```
css = b"""
button       {background: #fdd}
button:hover {background: #dfd}
"""
```

---

Full working code:

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import Gdk

# --- CSS ---

screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
provider = Gtk.CssProvider()

style_context = Gtk.StyleContext()
style_context.add_provider_for_screen(screen, provider, Gtk.STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_APPLICATION)

css = b"""
#green-entry {color: red; background: #dfd} 
#red-button {background: #fdd}
"""   # use prefix `b` or `.encode()` to create `bytes`

provider.load_from_data(css)
#provider.load_from_data("#green-entry {color: red; background: #dfd} #red-button {background: #fdd}".encode())
#provider.load_from_path('app.css')

# ---

class Entry(Gtk.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self)
        self.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)

        self.entry = Gtk.Entry(text='Hello World')

        self.button = Gtk.Button(label='button')
        self.button.connect('clicked', self.change_color)

        box = Gtk.Box()
        box.set_orientation(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
        box.add(self.entry)
        box.add(self.button)

        self.add(box)

        # --- assign ---
        
        #self.button.set_name('red-button')
        #self.entry.set_name('green-entry')
        
    def change_color(self, widget):
        self.button.set_name('red-button')
        self.entry.set_name('green-entry')

window = Entry()
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

---

Resource:

- [Gtk – 3.0: CSS Overview](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/css-overview.html)
- [Styling GTK3 in Python with CSS (Shallow Thoughts)](https://shallowsky.com/blog/programming/styling-gtk3-with-css-python.html)